# Call parent method in child class

Tags: python

I have a very simple situation:

I have this class:

```
class animal(object):
    def do_stuff(self):
        return self.__yell() 

class dog(animal):
    def yell(self):
        print("yelling")
```

I want to be able to call

```
d = dog() 
d.do_stuff()
```

however I get

> AttributeError: 'dog' object has no attribute '_animal__yell'

The parent class will implement do_stuff which will call each subclasses yell method, but this is not working

Comment: see https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super

Comment: Why are you prefixing `yell` as `__yell`?

Comment: [tag:python2] or [tag:python3]...

Comment: Looks like you are trying to call a child method from the parent class... `d.do_stuff()` should work fine. It is `self.__yell()` that is the problem

Answer (score 0):

Change `return self.__yell()` to `return self.yell()` and it will work. Just call it the way it's named.

```
In [1]: class animal(object):
   ...:     def do_stuff(self):
   ...:         return self.yell()
   ...:

In [2]: class dog(animal):
   ...:     def yell(self):
   ...:         print("yelling")
   ...:

In [3]: d = dog()

In [4]: d.do_stuff()
yelling
```

Comment: Actually, renaming `dog.yell` to dog.__yell` wouldn't work, since the double leading underscores trigger Python's name mangling. The rest of this answer is right on though (the solution is to not use double underscores!).

Answer (score 0):

`do_stuff` calls __yell(), which doesn't exist.  Either change `yell` to `__yell` (don't do this), or change `__yell` to `yell`.

```
In [24]: %paste
class animal(object):
    def do_stuff(self):
        return self.yell()


In [25]: %paste
class dog(animal):
    def yell(self):
        print("yelling")

In [26]: d = dog()

In [27]: d.do_stuff()
yelling
```